# How do you output a banner every 10 lines

Tags: c++, loops, return-value

I'm writing a program for my class and one of the instructions is for every 10 lines that pass, the program should pause and the header should be re-displayed on the new screen.  While that happens, an updated line count will be returned. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: It would be easier to guide you if we could see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well, the code is fairly long, so I don't want to put the entire thing in, but I will try to explain as much as I can.  The program will get an input of 2 numbers from the user.  The program will decide calculate the product of those two numbers without the ability to use multiplication.  So the 2nd line of the higher number will be floor(num / 2) and the smaller number will just be doubled.  The sum of the higher numbers product(if odd) will be the answer.  So I'll put in 26 and 53 and it'll get the product of the two in a round about way. I can figure out how to include the counter and pause

Answer (score 0):

[I do not have compiler right now, but code should work]

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> //IMPORTANT
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    int linecount = 1
    vector<string> header;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
        cout << linecount << ": " << "\n";
        linecount++;
        }

    header.push_back("####")
    header.push_back("ASDF")
    header.push_back("####")

    for(int j = 0; j <= header.size()-1; j++)
        {
        cout << linecount << ": " << header.at(j) << "\n";
        linecount += 1;
        }

    // (PAUSE)
    return 0;
    }
```

^ Should print 10 lines with linecount and then print header